# Android animation of concentric expanding fading circles

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-drawable

In Android, I am looking for as simple as "built-in" way as possible of creating either create a drawable or custom view of animating 4 concentric circles of slowly expanding radii.

[image: expanding fading concentric circles]

Where would be the best place to start?
Is it possible to do this in pure XML?
If not, can this be done using a single-layer drawable, or should I use a multi-layer drawable?

Thanks!

Comment: try looking through android Arsenal.  That would be your best first place to look for something like this.

Comment: Try searching about Animated Drawables.

Comment: @swooby I am also trying to do something like this but using only single layer drawable though i dont know how did you animated each item list in your drawable xml i asked a question but no replied on it yet. Please help

Comment: @SameerKhan1406 Sorry, I still haven't found an answer to this...yet...

Comment: @swooby Have you found any solution?

Comment: @DazzleR Nope, sorry, I have not.

Comment: @swooby this should help, https://github.com/skyfishjy/android-ripple-background

Comment: @DazzleR Dang! At first glance that looks exactly what I was looking for! Thanks! I'll give it a try!

Comment: @swooby Cool! I'll post it as an answer so that it may help others as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best place to start is [this repository](https://github.com/skyfishjy/android-ripple-background). It is an easy configurable Ripple Background animation for `Android`. Plug it in and you are ready to go. Here are the steps:

To set it up after installing it, Add `RippleBackground` to your layout like this,

```
<com.skyfishjy.library.RippleBackground
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/content"
    app:rb_color="#0099CC"
    app:rb_radius="32dp"
    app:rb_rippleAmount="4"
    app:rb_duration="3000"
    app:rb_scale="6">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/centerImage"
        android:src="@drawable/demoImage"/>
</com.skyfishjy.library.RippleBackground>
```

Then you can start the animation by overriding the onClick method like this,

```
final RippleBackground rippleBackground=(RippleBackground)findViewById(R.id.content);
ImageView imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.centerImage);
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        rippleBackground.startRippleAnimation();
    }
});
```

call the method `rippleBackground.stopRippleAnimation()` to stop the Animation.

Hope it helped.